# How to Use a Boolean Return Value in an If-statement without Invoking the Method Again

Tags: c#, if-statement, methods, return-value

How do I use the boolean return value of a method that has been invoked in one file to create an if-statement in a second file without invoking the method a second time?

As a simplified example, the following if-statement is nested within the CreateSubscription method in the APIHelper.cs file:

```
//APIHelper.cs
if (MakePayment(Order) == true)
 {
     //billing logic
 }
 else
 {
     return false;
 }
```

The following if-statement is in the Payment.cs file which references the APIHelper.cs file:

```
//Payment.cs
if (APIHelper.CreateSubscription(Order) == false)
{
    //error logic
    return;
}
```

I need to use the boolean return value of the MakePayment method from the APIHelper.cs file without invoking the MakePayment method a second time to create an if-statement like the following in the Payment.cs file. But in this case, because I invoke the method a second time to get the return value, the payment runs twice.

```
//Payment.cs
if (APIHelper.CreateSubscription(Order) == false && APIHelper.MakePayment(Order) == true)
{
    //error logic 1
    return;
}         
else if (APIHelper.MakePayment(Order) == false)
{
    //error logic 2
    return;
}
```

Comment: 1 - Don't compare to the bool literals, just use the results directly.  2 - Well, you can create a boolean variable and store the result there, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to just store the results in variables

```
bool subscriptionSucceeded = APIHelper.CreateSubscription( Order );
bool paymentSucceeded = APIHelper.MakePayment( Order );
if( !subscriptionSucceeded && paymentSucceeded )
{
    // Error logic 1
}
else if( !paymentSucceeded )
{
    // Error logic 2
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! That is much simpler than I made it out to be. I thought the method saved as a variable would execute as well, now I understand it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create a property to store the payment call. You can access the result of the property safely without reissuing the payment:

```
//APIHelper.cs
public PaymentResult { get; private set; }

// inside method
PaymentResult = MakePayment(Order);
if (PaymentResult == true)
 {
     //billing logic
 }
 else
 {
     return false;
 }
```

And access it like this:

```
//Payment.cs
if (APIHelper.CreateSubscription(Order) == false && APIHelper.PaymentResult == true)
{
    //error logic 1
    return;
}         
else if (APIHelper.PaymentResult == false)
{
    //error logic 2
    return;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Your answer combined with the variable example above expands my understanding of C# a lot.